# Unexpected output from awk printf

Tags: awk, osx, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
$ cat mycsv.csv 
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12”,”A”,”N”  
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12”,”A”,”N”  
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12”,”A”,”N”
```

Why does the following not print all the lines?

```
$awk -F "," '{printf}' mycsv.csv    
 ","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12”,”A”,”N””  

$awk -F "," '{printf $0}' mycsv.csv 
 ","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12”,”A”,”N””
```

Both should print all the lines right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `printf != print`

Comment: @SatoKatsura: print adds a new line that I dont want

Comment: `printf` needs a format string.

Comment: Jim, I've removed the bash tag fro your Q, since the question itself doesn't appear to involve bash-specific behavior, just awk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first argument to `printf`, whether it's C `printf()` or the `printf` utility or `awk`'s `printf()` is required<sup>1</sup> and is the **format**.

You want:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0}'
```

here. If you don't want an output record separator, you can also do:

```
awk -v ORS= '{print}' < mycsv.csv
```

Or even:

```
awk -v ORS= 1 < mycsv.csv
```

(`{print}` is the default action, *true* is the default condition, but you need to specify at least one action or condition, `1` is one way to say *true*).

Though here, `tr` would be enough:

```
tr -d '\n' < mycsv.csv
```

Or if you still want **one** trailing newline character so that output is still text:

```
paste -sd '\0' mycsv.csv
```

It also seems like your file has Microsoft-style  CRLF line delimiters, so you may want to also delete the CR characters:

```
tr -d '\r\n' < mycsv.csv
```

Or only the CRLF sequences with `awk` implementations that support more than single-character `RS` (which includes `gawk` and `mawk` but not macOS `awk`):

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS= 1 < mycsv.csv
```

Or:

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' -n ORS= 1 < mycsv.csv
```

that is with the `\r` optional to handle either Unix or MS-DOS line delimiters.

Or use things like `dos2unix` or `d2u` to convert the file to Unix format first.

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup> the format argument to `printf` is required in [the standard specification of the `awk` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). In `gawk` and `mawk` omitting it results in an error. In `busybox` `awk`, it's equivalent to `printf ""` and in `awk` derived from the original implementation (like on `macOS`), it's equivalent to `printf $0` (of little usefulness as it's still considered as a format, you'll still get an error if `$0` contains `%` characters).

Comment: This has the same result: `awk -F "," '{printf "%s", $0}' mycsv.csv` as the OP

Comment: @Jim, check the part about MS-DOS line delimiters. Try to pipe into `sed -n l` to check if the file contains CR character or other control characters.

Comment: Doing `sed -n l mycsv.csv` I only see `\r$` at the end of each line

Comment: @Jim, that means your file has CRLF delimiters, you'd need to convert it to unix format (see the part about dos2unix). If you remove the `\n`, the `\r` is left. `\r` when sent to a terminal makes the cursor move to the beginning of the line.